# JSON Object in Swift

Tags: json, swift, type-erasure

For the purpose of my app I'm using JSON objects that are defined like:

```
typealias JSONObject = [String:JSONValue]
```

Where JSON Value is a protocol to which possible types are conforming to:

```
protocol JSONValue {}
extension String:      JSONValue {}
extension Int:         JSONValue {}
extension Double:      JSONValue {}
extension Bool:        JSONValue {}
extension NSNull:      JSONValue {}
extension JSONObject:  JSONValue {}
```

(I prefer using this way instead of creating a JSONValue enum with .string(value), .int(value) etc... My code is private and no-one will be adding other extensions)

To handle arrays, I've added:

```
extension [JSONValue]: JSONValue {}
```

So that any JSONValue can be a primitive, an array, or a dictionary (JSONObject)

Everything is working fine. I'm just having an issue with arrays. See this example :

```
var myObject = JSONObject()
myObject["primitive"] = "OK"
myObject["array"] = ["OK"]

let myObjectAsJSONValue: JSONValue = myObject // OK


var myArray = [JSONObject]()
myArray.append(myObject)

let myArrayAsJSONValue: JSONValue = myArray // Failing (Protocol 'JSONValue' requires the types 'JSONObject' (aka 'Dictionary<String, any JSONValue>') and 'any JSONValue' be equivalent)
```

I don't understand the error I'm getting since JSONObject conforms to JSONValue (so can be handled as "any JSONValue")

Any help??

Thanks!

**Edit:** Fixed my issue by replacing:

```
extension [JSONValue]: JSONValue {}
```

With:

```
extension Array : JSONValue where Element : JSONValue {}
```

I don't really understand the difference but it seems to work...

Comment: Well, you could make your `Array` reference the protocol type instead in your previous implementation, like: `var myArray = [JSONValue]()`. This will compile fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the edit, you should write the array extension like this:

```
extension Array : JSONValue where Element : JSONValue {}
```

This is different from `extension [JSONValue] ...` in that `extension [JSONValue]` declares an extension on only *one* type - `Array<any JSONValue>`.

So if you just declare `myArray` as:

```
var myArray = [any JSONValue]()
```

there will be no error.

The `myArray` in your code has type `Array<JSONObject>`. This is a different type from `Array<any JSONValue>`, and therefore `extension [JSONValue]` does not apply to it - it does not conform to `JSONValue`.

If the extension is `extension Array : JSONValue where Element : JSONValue`, then the extension applies to *all* `Array` types, **where the `Element` type conforms to `JSONValue`**. Since `JSONObject` conforms to `JSONValue`, `Array<JSONObject>` does too.

Comment: Thank you very much for these clear explanations!! I got it